# Teasing Dashboard reports. Use dummy data or empty reports?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, dashboard, intuition, analytics

I’m currently designing a dashboard that relies on having a connection to Google Analytics. For the users that aren’t connected to GA, what would be best to show for them? We want to have a strong CTA to connect to google analytics while teasing the reports that would become available once they’re connected.

Option 1. Show empty reports, with the “connect to GA” call to action. Tables and graphs would be present but with no data in them

Option 2. Show dummy data with some sort of treatment to indicate that this is not real data and again with the “connect to GA” call to action

Option 3. something else

Answer (score 1):

Could you use your own analytics data to show potential customers? Places like [Baremetrics](https://baremetrics.com) have done this for years (screen shots are typically their own numbers). Also the GA data is anonymized (per Google's TOS) so you shouldn't have to worry too much about the content.

Alternately you could opt not to show any data but you could highlight the findings that are available (**remember the value of data is NOT the numbers its what you learn from it**). This would give you the opportunity to actually sell the value of what you're providing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it might be even matter of marketing but, seeing graphs/tables with an empty data not a solution I'd choose to display.

Instead, I reccomend blurred avarage analytics result, or there might be some gif visualising standing out results to make a more impression on the viewer and then a CTA button to make the integration below.